# Find and Replace string using sed gives error

Tags: shell, sed

I am using shell script. My requirement is to find and replace the string. The string contains "/" char as well. I am getting error sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command. Can someone tell how should i replace the string which has "/"?

```
#!/bin/bash
...
search_string="../conf/TestSystem/Inst1.xml"
rep="Inst1/Instrument.xml"

sed -i 's|${line}|${rep}/g' MasterConfiguration.xml
```

I tried using another sed command but that one also gave error sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'

```
sed -e "s/${line}/${rep}/g" MasterConfiguration.xml > tempfile
```

Comment: double quote for your sed action part instead of single quote if you want substitution of variable content, the last `/g` should be `|g` because you start your `s` action wiuth a `|`and not a `/`. Also search string must ideally escape the dot character in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you deal with shell-variables you have to get them out of the "sed-string":

For example:

```
sed -e "s/"${line}"/"${rep}"/g" MasterConfiguration.xml > tempfile
```

Otherwise sed will treat the chars as-is and search for `${line}` literally:
[image]
As you see, nothing happens here.

Furthermore, if your variables contain `/` you need to use another delimiter for sed. I tend to use `~` in such a case, but you're free to use other chars - just be consequent and don't mix them like in your first example-sed-command:

```
sed 's~'${line}'~'${rep}'/g' //WRONG
sed 's~'${line}'~'${rep}'~g' //RIGHT
```

Combine both and it will work:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -i "s#${line}#${rep}#g" MasterConfiguration.xml
```

**Problem:**

Instead you have,

```
sed -i "s|${line}|${rep}/g" MasterConfiguration.xml
```

It should be,

```
sed -i "s|${line}|${rep}|g" MasterConfiguration.xml
```

**Syntax:**

```
sed "s|pattern|replacement|g"
```